# How to design not in/exclude query behaviour

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles

The title might not be very clear but i could not figure out a better one. Here is the problem. I have a Scope interface which gives all the pages where a QueryEngine should query in.

```
interface Scope{
  Set<Page> getPages();    
}

interface QueryEngine{
  void query(Scope scope){
     queryIn(scope.getPages());
  }
}
```

There is another type of scope which says query all the pages **other than the ones it provides**.
I was trying to model this behavior.

```
interface ExcludeScope extends Scope{
}
```

In which case i have to do something like below in QueryEngine

```
interface QueryEngine{
  void query(Scope scope){
     if(scope instanceof ExcludeScope){
        queryInPagesOtherThan(scope.getPages());
     }else{
        queryIn(scope.getPages());
     }
  }
}
```

Or should it be something which is driven by a boolean

```
interface Scope{
  Set<Page> getPages();   
  boolean shouldExclude();
}
```

I feel both the above approaches would lead to if, else conditions in the QueryEngine
which means that it is not closed for modifications.

How to design such a behaviour? What should be the approach one should follow while tackling any design problem? Should we start by checking whether SOLID principles were followed? Should we look to classify the problem under a design pattern thus arrive at a solution?

Comment: If your `ExcludeScope` returns the pages who should not be processed I would say that your interface contract is broken - if you state that the interface method returns the pages to be processed, returning the pages not to be processed with the `ExcludeScope` is contradictory.

Comment: yes, i agree. Should there be some operator based approach in this case? Like NOT operator for exclusion, OR operator for query in all the pages?

Comment: You could also invert the control - for example, the `QueryEngine` asks a scope for each page if the page should be processed and the `Scope` returns `true` or `false` - then, your `ExcludeScope` implementation could just hold a list of pages *not* to be processed and check against them.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the root of your problem is in this sentence:

> There is another type of scope which says query all the pages other than the ones it provides".

Scope has nothing to do with querying, it should only represent a subset of all elements. You seem to want to perform a query in a different way, so I would suggest to go for a new method in the `QueryEngine`:

```
interface QueryEngine{
  void query(Scope scope){
    ...
  }
  void queryComplement(Scope scope) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, the query method should reflect what it will do with the scope.

Comment: If you agree, could you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to perform an inversion of control: The `QueryEngine` asks a `Scope` whether to process a page or not and the `Scope` answers independently `true` or `false`, similar to

```
interface Scope {
  boolean process(Page page);
}

interface QueryEngine {
  void query(Scope scope, Set<Page> pages) {
    Set<Pages> pagesToProcess = new HashSet<Page>();

    for (Page page : pages) {
      if (scope.process(page)) {
        pagesToProcess.add(page);
      }
    }

    queryIn(pagesToProcess);
  }
}

class IncludeScope implements Scope {
  private static final Set<Page> INCLUDING_PAGES = ...

  public boolean process(Page page) {
    return INCLUDING_PAGES.contains(page);
  }
}

class ExcludeScope implements Scope {
  private static final Set<Page> EXCLUDING_PAGES = ...

  public boolean process(Page page) {
    return !EXCLUDING_PAGES.contains(page);
  }
}
```